# Is it possible to have bandwidth or transfer caps with Linux on Rackspace Cloud?

Tags: bandwidth, linux, bandwidth-control, rackspace-cloud

I just set up a virtual Ubuntu 10.04 server with Rackspace Cloud. Is it possible to set a limit on the amount of data transferred within a given length of time? Ideally I would get an email notice when a spike occurs.

The reason I want this is because I don't want to get any nasty surprises in case I get hacked or if the site gets really popular for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. There are a lot of FAQs/forums out there that give advice on bandwidth throttling.

Try here: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/bandwidth-throttling-347385/

Comment: I'm actually looking for something like a daily/weekly/monthly cap (like 10GB/month), rather than throttling it to, say 100KB/s.